# Emulate/Force 256 color palette in Unity3D

Tags: unity-game-engine, shader

I'm currently working on a 3D project that uses billboarded sprites for characters, but 3D art for the environments. With anti-aliasing and a low resolution, the environment is somewhat close to looking like pixel art, but the smoothness of shading on the meshes from lights ruins the effect.

I was wondering if there's any kind of post processing that could force the final image to use a 256 colour palette of my own devising, essentially shifting each pixel to the closest match in the palette.

The example below is what I'm looking for; a 3D scene, but the colours downgraded to a smaller palette.

[image: example image]

If there's no post-processing solution for this, would I be accomplishing this with shaders on the meshes? And if so, what direction should I try to achieve this look?

Comment: I found a post-processing package on the asset store, but after trying it I see that the post-processing approach won't work. What I really need is a shader per asset that limits the colours to a stricter palette (like 8 or 12) in order to achieve the desired effect.

Comment: It will be a lot of work doing that per shader. I don't see how a post-processing solution won't work, however.

Comment: The problem with the post-processing effect is that instead of making a lit 3D object look more like a sprite, it made the whole scene look like a mid-90s videogame rendered cutscene.

It might be a bit of work per shader, but since my materials are just flat colours, it would mean that anything with a particular hue gets a shader specific to that hue. Like all the cold, grey stones get a shader that restricts that material to a palette ranging from black, various slightly blue grey shades, up to an almost slightly blue white. Or, at least that's how I think it will work.

Comment: What you could do is create an editor script or menu item that loops through all materials in the Assets folder, and modifies the [color property](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material-color.html) to fall under the specified palette. You can do this per object if you want separate palettes  by using a MonoBehaviour which manages its own renderer's material's color. If you want something like this to happen *after* lighting calculations and so on (like in the image in your answer), there's no other way but to use a post processing effect or modify each used shader.

Comment: Thanks. Currently teaching myself shaders so I can figure out how to do the fragment shader I need to do this.